# Can't deploy random forest model

Tags: dataframe, input, deployment, random-forest, prediction

emphasized textHalo I'm new to shinny and R, but can't deploy random forest model because the dataframe that I made didn't exist and error "**

> Error in $<-.data.frame: replacement has 0 rows, data has 1`

Anyone with same problem ? thank you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: below is my reprex